# Каковы синонимы слова "очеловечиться"? / What are synonyms for "очеловечиться"?

Tags: выбор-слова, синонимы

Каково семантическое поле этого глагола? Пожалуйста, предлагайте варианты в одно слово. What are semantic implications for the word? Please offer one-word Russian options; thanks.

Comment: Would you mind offering some context for the word?

Comment: Well, let's take it virtually... or rather literally; imagine a god/a spirit / a daemon becoming a human being in flash and blood.

Comment: Speaking about spirits and daemons, it's воплотиться - literary, "to acquire flesh".

Comment: @Manjusri That would more likely be an "incarnation" or "embodiment", both translated as "воплощение", not "очеловечивание" ("humanization").

Comment: I'm not sure if Manjusri can respond (because of suspended account) but the (question + comment) combination is a bit strange because the word `очеловечиться` is **not** usually used in the meaning "god/spirit/daemon becoming man". See the answer of Andry for the most common usage.

Comment: When talking about Christ then `вочеловечиться` is usually used.

Answer (score 1):

Очеловечение - одухотворение, оживление, олицетворение.

Comment: одухотворение это кажется, что ровно наоборот.

Comment: Welcome to Russian Language and Usage Beta! Usually we prefer longer and more elaborated answers on short answers. If you can improve your answer by adding detail, context, examples, and backing up with references, this would increase your answer's quality. Poor and/or repetitive answers risk being down-voted and subsequently removed. In case it gets deleted, you can still edit it; if you improve it and wish for it to get undeleted, please use **flag for moderator attention**, then choose **custom** and shortly explain the situation.

Answer (score 1):

Очеловечиться - вообще так нельзя говорить. Только в разговорном языке. Означает обрести культуру, начать выполнять принятые обычаи, отказаться от наркотической или алкогольной зависимости, раскаяться в злодеяниях.

Comment: I agree with you in your explanation of the standard meaning of this word. I would not use "очеловечиться" in the meaning that Manjusri mentioned in the comment and form that moment on the most discussed here: a god becoming man. I would not agree though with you that очеловечиться is strictly colloquial. I think it is at least half way to a common literary word.

Answer (score 0):

Олицетвориться, персонифицироваться (в значении "принять образ лица, человека").

Answer (score 0):

Well, the closest word I guess is `воплощение` (and the verb derived `воплотиться` to be precise, since you are asking about verb), one of it's meaning stands for what you are exactly for act of embodiment in flesh, or incarnation. So, in Russian  theological tradition we talk about "воплощение Бога во Христе".

The very word [origins from](http://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%BB%D0%BE%D1%89%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5) `во плоти`/`въплъти` , literally in flesh/in skin - in Old Slavic).

We can used this word talking not only in context of Christianity. It is perfectly valid to say about reincarnation of any deity, for example, "воплощение Вишну" or "воплощение Рамы".

There is another synonymous (in some contexts) word, `претворение` (verb form is `претвориться`, shouldn't be confused with `притвориться`), but be warned, as far as I know, in Christian literature it is not typical to use it in this sense. Moreover it is traditionally used in phrase eucharistic context: "претворение вина в кровь, а хлеба - в тело Христово".

Comment: The Christian concepts are more commonly called *преложение* ("transmutation") and *пресуществление* ("transsubstantiation").

Comment: @Quassnoi, кроме того, особенно в  католической традиции и слово транссубстанциация тоже допустимо. Да, вы правы, слово претворение оно как бы из "разговорного теологического" (но тем не менее общепонятного и более того, допустимого), я просто решил не усложнять, потому что это уже - уточнение терминологии относящейся к вопросу лишь косвенно.

Comment: Also, обратиться человеком.

Comment: Вочеловечиться is used to describe Christ being born as a human being.